# How to make SELECT faster

Tags: sql-server

I have this `SELECT` using SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT  
    dcodigo AS cuenta,
    SUM(dvalordeb) AS sumadebitop, 
    SUM(dvalorcre) AS sumacreditop
FROM 
    diario
WHERE 
    diario.anulado = 0 
    AND LEN(diario.dcodigo ) > 0 
    AND MONTH(diario.dfecha) <= 11 
    AND YEAR(diario.dfecha) = 2015
    AND diario.tipo1 <> 'CI'
GROUP BY 
    dcodigo
```

but it takes about 2,8 minutes. What can I do for faster execution?

Table `diario` is indexed by: `dcodigo`, `dfecha` and `tipo1`, and has over 600,000 rows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have any indexes on your table?, anyway, you should at least change your filters on `dfecha`: `AND dfecha >= '20150101' AND dfecha < '20151201'`

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell without seeing your table structure, indexes or even an execution plan for this query.

Comment: you're not using indexes on dfecha; anytime you parse the date it can't use the index anymore.  unless you have a len(diario.dcodigo) function based index, it can't use that index either.

Comment: The indexes you listed won't help for any of your where conditions except the `<>'CI'` which probably isn't that helpful anyway.

Comment: Read about [sargable, especially point 2](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/55535/sargable-queries-in-sql-server-with-examples/)

Comment: Thank you, I am going to dismiss functions

Answer (score 1):

try this:

if `dfecha` is date only, then

```
SELECT dcodigo as cuenta,
    sum(dvalordeb) sumadebitop, 
    sum(dvalorcre) sumacreditop
FROM diario 
WHERE anulado = 0 
   AND dcodigo is not null 
   and dcodigo <> ''
   AND dfecha between '20150101' and '20151031' 
   AND tipo1 <> 'CI'
GROUP BY dcodigo
```

if `dfecha` has date and time, then

```
SELECT dcodigo as cuenta,
    sum(dvalordeb) sumadebitop, 
    sum(dvalorcre) sumacreditop
FROM diario 
WHERE anulado = 0 
   AND dcodigo is not null 
   and dcodigo <> ''
   AND dfecha >='20150101' 
       and dfecha < '20151101' 
   AND tipo1 <> 'CI'
GROUP BY dcodigo
```

Comment: the `dcodigo like '%%'` it's a bad idea, might as well search for `LEN` instead

Comment: Ups, this does not cover the last day of october, if the given value has got a time... [Bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) Better is `>= StartDaten AND < DayAfterEndDateWithoutTime`

Comment: I was trying to make it sargable, (but if % is at the beginning)...  and thought the condition was `Len() > 10`...  ....

Comment: Thanks Charles, I am going to test it

Answer (score 1):

Conditions based on function calls will not benefit from the indexes.

Replace `LEN(diario.dcodigo)>0` by `diario.dcodigo<>''`. But the fundamental question is whether this column does contain empty strings at all. I suppose that empty fields just contain `NULL`. In that case you should test `diario.dcodigo IS NOT NULL`. If it can be both test like this `NOT (diario.dcodigo IS NULL OR diario.dcodigo = '')` and don't forget the parentheses.

As Lamak commented, dismiss the MONTH and YEAR functions and test against date constants instead.